# Is it "Thats why!" or "That's why!"?

Tags: orthography, rules

I see it spelled both ways, what is the right way ?

So far I lived by the rule that apostrophe s means possession and without the apostrophe it is a simple abbreviation. Or is it more complicated ? (Sorry, non-native speaker.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no word "thats" in English.

"That's why" is a contraction of "that is why".

The apostrophe is used for both possession and contraction, but for the pronoun **that** it would be very unusual to use the possessive.

An exception is the word **it**, where **it's** is a contraction of "it is", and **its** is possessive (following the grammar of he/his, she/hers).

Comment: Too many thises and thats clutter up a sentence. But not according to the editors of the [Routledge Encyclopaedia of Philosophy](https://www.rep.routledge.com/articles/overview/east-asian-philosophy/v-1/sections/ars-contextualis-the-art-of-contextualizing) : _From the always unique place one occupies within the cosmos of classical East Asia, one construes and interprets the order of the world around one as contrasting ‘thises’ and ‘thats’– ‘this person’ and ‘that person’ – more or less proximate to oneself._

Comment: @MichaelHarvey from an internet trawl for occurrences of **thats**?